# How to get Video Thumbnails from api link?

Tags: flutter, api

I want to display list of videos with thumbnails from api.

Here is the api response as below.

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "video": [
    {
      "video_id": "609cb28a0760c",
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvvHNtlz20Q&list=RDEvvHNtlz20Q&start_radio=1",
      "search_by": "",
      "topic_id": "609cb1dce30aa",
      "chapter_id": "609cb13f497e3",
      "subject_id": "5e32874c714fa",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "topic_name": "test topic",
      "active": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

From above response i created Model Class as below in videomodel.dart file.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final videoModel = videoModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

VideoModel videoModelFromJson(String str) =>
    VideoModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String videoModelToJson(VideoModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class VideoModel {
  VideoModel({
    required this.success,
    required this.video,
  });

  int success;
  List<Video> video;

  factory VideoModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VideoModel(
        success: json["success"],
        video: List<Video>.from(json["video"].map((x) => Video.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "video": List<dynamic>.from(video.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Video {
  Video({
    required this.videoId,
    required this.url,
    required this.searchBy,
    required this.topicId,
    required this.chapterId,
    required this.subjectId,
    required this.mediumId,
    required this.standardId,
    required this.topicName,
    required this.active,
  });

  String videoId;
  String url;
  String searchBy;
  String topicId;
  String chapterId;
  String subjectId;
  String mediumId;
  String standardId;
  String topicName;
  String active;

  factory Video.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Video(
        videoId: json["video_id"],
        url: json["url"],
        searchBy: json["search_by"],
        topicId: json["topic_id"],
        chapterId: json["chapter_id"],
        subjectId: json["subject_id"],
        mediumId: json["medium_id"],
        standardId: json["standard_id"],
        topicName: json["topic_name"],
        active: json["active"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "video_id": videoId,
        "url": url,
        "search_by": searchBy,
        "topic_id": topicId,
        "chapter_id": chapterId,
        "subject_id": subjectId,
        "medium_id": mediumId,
        "standard_id": standardId,
        "topic_name": topicName,
        "active": active,
      };
}
```

Here is the Function i created in apimanager.dart file.

```
Future<List<Video>> getVideo() async {
    final videoUrl =
        "$baseUrl/videos/get_by_standard_medium_subject_chapter_id?subject_id=5e32874c714fa&medium_id=5d15938aa1344&standard_id=5d1594e283e1a&chapter_id=609cb13f497e3";
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final videoData = videoModelFromJson(response.body);
      final List<Video> videos = videoData.video;
      return videos;
    } else {
      return <Video>[];
    }
  }
```

And last is view code as below in video_widget.dart file.

```
class _VideoWidgetState extends State<VideoWidget> {
  var _videos = <Video>[];
  late bool _loading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loading = true;

    ApiManager().getVideo().then((videos) {
      setState(() {
        _videos = videos;
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: null == _videos ? 0 : _videos.length,
        //itemCount: _subjects.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          Video video = _videos[index];
        });
  }
}
```

So how can i display the list of videos with the thumbnails?

Comment: There is no thumbnail property in the api response you have shown, so what do you exactly want to ask?
How to create a list item?

Comment: i know how to display list items but i want to display list of videos with thumbnails, and the video url in api is youtube video so how can i get the thumbnail of video?

Comment: Please mention that it is the youtube api or atleast put a tag, how will anyone know what kind of api you are using?

Comment: no its not youtube api its a local api created in code igniter.

Comment: okay I got it, i solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simply using YoutubeVideoController I solved the problem.

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: null == _videos ? 0 : _videos.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Video video = _videos[index];

            var url = video.url;

            YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
              initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.getThumbnail(videoId: url),
              flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
                autoPlay: false,
                mute: false,
                disableDragSeek: false,
                loop: false,
                isLive: false,
                forceHD: false,
              ),
            );
            return YoutubePlayer(
              controller: _controller,
            );
          },
        ),
```